# ng-repeat - filter by function in datastructure

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array with json objects which contains a function

```
items = [...{
   id:1,
   isActive: function(){
     this.id < activeId;
   }
}...];
```

In a directive elsewhere I use this json array in an `ng-repeat`. I want to filter with regards to the function.

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items | filter:{isActive():true}"/>
```

However, this doesn't work. I can do it with properties, but not with function calls. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use custom filter function (make sure to `return` from `isActive` object methods btw):

```
$scope.isActive = function(el) {
    return el.isActive();
};
```

and use it like this

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items | filter:isActive">{{i.id}}</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Ib8LINdHNBPDfXOBusez?p=preview

Comment: Allright, is there no way to do it inline? What if I only want to iterate trough inactive elements? I can't do `filter:!isActive`... Do I have to write two custom filter functions?

Comment: Yes, using this approach, you would have to write an additional function. That is why I recommended writing a custom AngularJS filter below, so that the same functionality could be reused whenever and however you need it. If you get to another page in your app where the same functionality is needed, you will be repeating yourself, it's better to keep code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to return the result of your function:

```
$scope.items = [
  {
      id: 1,
      isActive: function() {
          return this.id < activeId;
      }
  },
  {/* ... */}
];
```

Then, in your HTML, simply use the [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items|orderBy:'isActive()'">{{item.id}} - {{item.isActive()}}</li>
</ul>
```

That should work.

***EDIT***

Sorry, misunderstood the question. I don't believe the 'filter' $filter will take a method as the expression. You are probably better off writing your own filter. I took a quick stab at it, but have only tested it lightly, more thorough testing would be required before using it.

```
/**
 * Defines a filter on the $filter provider that will call a method
 * to filter objects inside of ngRepeat.
 *
 * @return {Function}
 *    @param {Array} - the array to loop through
 *    @param {String} - the Object method name
 *    @param {Any} - the value to match against 
 *    @return {Array} - the resultant array
 */
.filter('evalMethod', [function() {
    return function(array, method, expected) {
        var results = [];
        /** 
          * loop through all items in the array
          * and bind the results to the results object
          */
        angular.forEach(array, function(item, key) {
            /** 
             * call the method against the item context,
             * if it returns as expected, push it into the results array
             */
            if (item[method].call(item) == expected) {
                this.push(item);
            }
        }, results);
        return results;
    };
}]);
```

And then using markup like:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items|evalMethod:'isActive':true">{{item.id}} - {{item.isActive()}}</li>
```

Then, if you want to use this inside the controller (or anywhere else), just include $filter as a dependency and call.

```
$filter('evalMethod')($scope.items, 'isActive', true);
```

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this looks very complicated, in such case it's perhaps better to do custom filter function and put it on the scope..

Comment: All this is is defining a custom filter to be reused anywhere on the app ([see this tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)). Putting a function on the $scope like that would generally be advised against as you don't want to pollute your $scope with unnecessary functions. If it makes you feel better, I will comment the filter to let you know what's happening.